# Best way to test redux failure action in a redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

Say I have a redux connected react component like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  renderErrorMessage() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;

    if(!errorMessage) {
      return;
    }

    // render error message
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Menu location={this.props.location.pathname}/>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            { this.renderErrorMessage() }
            { this.props.children }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.get('errorMessage')
  };
};

App.propTypes = {
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  resetErrorMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  resetErrorMessage
})(App);
```

And I have a failure action like:

```
export function fetchResultsFailure(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RESULTS_FAILURE,
    error
  }
}
```

And my reducer looks like this:

```
function errorMessage(state = null, action) {
  const { type, error } = action;

  if(type === ActionTypes.RESET_ERROR_MESSAGE) {
    return null;
  } else if (error) {
    return action.error;
  }

  return state;
};
```

I am using this with redux-saga and the failure condition might be called like this:

```
function* fetchEntity(entity, apiFn) {
  yield put(entity.request());
  const { response, error } = yield call(apiFn);

  if(response) {
    yield put(entity.success(response));
  } else {
    console.log(error);
    yield put(entity.failure(error));
  }

};
```

How do I go about testing this?  I would like to test this end to end and that the error message is returned

Comment: do you mean a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must **unit test** the individual components. E.g. make sure that if you pass your component an error prop, it renders it.

Secondly, **end-to-end** testing is about testing the entire app. So to test that the error works in end-to-end testing, you need to work out what would cause that error (e.g. database is down) and replicate that (unplug your database server :)).

You can stub/mock out various interfaces (e.g. intercept network requests to force an error) and speed up tests.

For all this you probably want to automate it with something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Finally, my opinion is that you don't need to unit test stuff that isn't your code. That is, you don't need to test that Redux's `connect` does what it says it will, you don't need to test that your components import the right modules, etc. It might sound obvious but I think once you stop thinking about multi-module unit tests the easier your tests will be.